# Establishing One-to-One Relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, one-to-one

When working with a one-to-one relationship at the database level, we (I?) often end up implementing what is actually a one-to-many relationship.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE master (masterId INT PRIMARY KEY)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    childId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    masterId INT,
    CONSTRAINT child_master_fk FOREIGN KEY (masterId) REFERENCES master (masterId))
```

While a single `child` can only reference a single `master`, there is nothing preventing multiple `child`s from referencing the same `master`, resulting in a one-to-many relationship.

When generating an entity data model from such a database set-up, this gets reflected with the fact that the master entity will contain a reference to the child entity, but the child entity will have a master entity collection.

Since I logically see the relationship as one-to-one, I never expect the child's master collection to contain more than one element; thus, I'd like the child entity to have a single master reference instead of a collection.

What is the correct way of accomplishing this? Creating a two-way foreign key constraint at the database level? Tweaking the generated model?

Answer (score 0):

Tweak the model. Add a singular reference property that returns the single instance and just ignore the collection property. Then set the singular property to be ignored by EF in your mapping configuration.

It isn't what I'd call elegant, but such sacrifices often have to be made when using EF with a pre-existing database.

Comment: Would this let me navigate from master to child?

Comment: Yes, sort of. If you have a Master entity that has a generated Children collection property, you can hand-code another property onto Master and tell EF to ignore it. Assuming that hand-coded property is named something like OnlyChild then you could use `Master.OnlyChild` to refer to it. The big caveat here is nothing would be preventing you or someone else from directly using the Children property to add more than one child. It might be better to just endure the minor annoyance of having to call `Children.FirstOrDefault()` to access the child.

Comment: No, EF would be completely unaware of `Master.OnlyChild`. The getter for the property would need to retrieve an entry from the `Master.Children` collection using either `Children.FirstOrDefault()` or `Children.SingleOrDefault()` depending on whether you want it to throw an exception if an extra child gets added somehow. The property's setter would check if `Master.Children` already has an entry (possibly throw an exception if more than one) remove that entry and add the new one.